# Battlestar Galactica Style Lens Flare?

Tags: video

**How are lens flares akin to that in shows like Battlestar Galactica, SGU, etc. achieved?**

Here is an example:

[image: Lens Flare Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the type of lens flare you're looking for is anamorphic lens flare.

Comment: Best to do it with a real anamorphic lens, but those are crazy expensive, and I hear diopters are a PITA to focus.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All the main editing packages have lens flare as an option, so this is incredibly easy in post.

To do it live is less controllable, but is still simple - in fact avoiding lens flare is one of the challenges, as many lens configurations give unpleasant flare when shooting anywhere near the sun.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an editing package, you can see if any of the popular lens flare plug-ins are available for it. For example:

[mFlare](http://www.motionvfx.com/mplugs-1.html)

[Knoll Light Factory](http://www.redgiant.com/products/knoll-light-factory/)

I know that Motion has a built-in lens flare generator. I'd assume most other packages do, too.